# Encrypt Datatable server side response with Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash, coldfusion

Can someone advise me how can I encrypt the XHR response with Coldfusion? I have some tables that I create with Datatable, BootstrapTable and serverside function in a CFC.The problem is that the JSON that I get back is unencrypted so anyone can see the column names and other sensitive informations.As I don't have a lot of experience with Coldfusion, and JS I couldn't find a good implementation for this. Is encrypt function better that hash function? For the login part I created a hash system with salt SHA-512 system. But I couldn't find a way to encrypt the JSON in the CFC and decrypt it in the FrontEnd with JS or CF. I use Coldfusion 9 Enterprise. Any advise is helpful.

Comment: Aren't you using `https` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler Yes, I use https..but the XHR response can be seen as it is a json response, so any user can see that response.

Comment: Since you have to decrypt in the front-end with JS and use those values to render things, anybody can see the column names after you decrypt them.

Answer (score 3):

You want to encrypt the data that's going to be displayed in the HTML anyway? To @AlexBaban's point, this is nothing to be concerned with. If you want to "hide" the actual database column names, just select them with an alias: `select tableID as totally_not_my_pk_column`.

You should only be retuning data related to a logged in user's roles or privileges. There should be no "sensitive information" returned that they aren't allowed to see.

**Update:**

> For example if i enable the sorting for 2 columns and i set a different name when i try to sort one of those columns because the query is done again to display the new set of data it needs the name of the column otherwise it will break

How are you handling the data submissions? If you submit to a function with arguments, you can do data type validation, data requirement validation and abstract out the communication between the grid control and the database. If your function argument was `sort_column`, you pass the grid's sort control value and handle mapping the "alias" to the column's real name in your query.

Comment: Yes you are right but datatable and other JS driven add-on needs the actual name of the columns in the database so you can search through  those columns. For example if i enable the sorting for 2 columns and i set a different name when i try to sort one of those columns because the query is done again to display the new set of data it needs the name of the column otherwise it will break.Also in the JS code i have a lot of rules so i can display some data and I would prefer to hide those rules.I know that there are ways, for example  cryptojs or encoding the code.But I would prefer some advices

Comment: If the column names are being sent back to front-end Javascript, then it doesn't do you any good to encrypt them. Whoever consumes that data can see it all anyway.

Comment: If it is view/read only data, consider using a SQL View and build your queries against that.  Then you can alias all the columns and be able to search/sort on the aliases.